# Where does it say that one who already said the morning blessings can go and repeat them as prayer leader?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shacharis-morning-prayer, chazzan-prayer-leader, motzi-yedei-chovato

I was told that someone who had already said the morning blessings can go and repeat them as prayer leader. This was said even though it seems to me that no-one relies on the prayer leader to acquit them of their obligation for these blessings. Is the teaching correct and if so what is the source?

Comment: S”A 6:4 is pretty clear that this is not an option

Answer (score 1):

[O Ch 6 (2) MB 10](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.6.2?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=he) says

> עיין במ"א ופמ"ג ושארי אחרונים שהסכימו דאפילו ש"ץ שבירך בביתו שוב לא
> יברך בבהכ"נ דבימינו הכל בקיאים וכל אחד מברך לעצמו ואין רוצה לצאת בברכת
> הש"ץ
>
> a) See the M”A and PM”G and other acharonim who agree that even a
> chazzan who said the blessings at home should not say them in shul
> because in our days everyone is practised in these blessings and
> everyone makes theblessings for themselves and does not intend  to be
> covered by the chazzan.
>
> ע"כ במקום שהמנהג שהש"ץ אומר כל הברכות בצבור כמו במקומותינו שהמנהג כן
> בימים נוראים שמברך בצבור גם ענט"י ואשר יצר וברכת התורה יזהר מתחלה שלא
> יברך אותם בביתו.
>
> b) Therefore where the custom is that the chazzan says all the
> blessings as in our locations ….. he should take care not to say the
> blessings at home.
>
> ואם אירע שכבר בירך אותם בביתו יראה לבקש לאחד מהשומעים שעדיין לא בירך
> שיכוין לצאת בברכתו אך אז יהיה זהיר הש"ץ מאוד להשמיע כל לשון הברכה ולא
> כמו שנוהגין באיזה מקום שהש"ץ משמיע רק לשון תחלת הברכה וסופה דכיון
> שכונתו אז בהברכה להוציא צריך השומע להשמיע כל לשון הברכה:
>
> c) And if it turned out that he did say them at home then he should
> see to it to ask one of those listening who has not yet said the
> blessings that this person should intend to be covered by the blessing
> of the chazzan who should carefully enunciate all the blessing …..
> because since he intends to cover the listener he must cause all the
> blessing to be heard.

So we see from (a and b) that someone who had already said the morning blessings should **not** repeat them as prayer leader but (c) if he must  repeat them as prayer leader he needs to specially set up someone who will be covered by the blessings.

Comment: The question remains if the person you spoke with has a different source